# Как PHP mail() узнаёт об отправке письма?

Tags: email, php, sendmail

PHP скриптом отправляется некоторое письмо при помощи встроенной функции `mail()`. Функция `mail()` завершилась успешно и вернула `TRUE`. Это можно с уверенностью утверждать, т.к. в коде стоит конструкция вроде:

```
if (mail(...)) {
    $this->_log("Письмо успешно отправлено");
}
```

И в логе есть запись об этом, известен момент времени. При этом письмо до получателя не дошло, и в логе почтовика нет никаких упоминаний о том, что такое письмо вообще приходило в почтовик для отправки (письмо в логе искали по времени отправления и получателям, часовой пояс настроен правильно). При этом обычно письма этим скриптом отправляются успешно, данный случай неотправки единичный.

Сервер работает на Debian, используется PHP 5.4.27, для опции php.ini `sendmail_path` используется значение по умолчанию ("`/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i`"), в качестве почтовика используется sendmail 2.7.1-1+squeeze1.

Подскажите пожалуйста как PHP функция `mail()` узнаёт о том, что письмо успешно отправлено? То есть в каких случаях `mail()` возвращает `TRUE`? И как может быть так, что функция `mail()` вернула `TRUE`, а в логе sendmail нет даже упоминания о письме? Я предполагаю, что `mail()` просто анализирует exit-code запущенного процесса из `sendmail_path` и если 0, то возвращает TRUE. Но это лишь моё предположение. Я не смог найти ни в документации, ни где бы то ни было ещё информацию о том, как это происходит на самом деле.

Comment: а вы на debian используете  sendmail ? ссзб. Успешность по exitcode скорее всего. Если он 0 - успешно.

Comment: Использую не лично я, а наш администратор, это его выбор. А в чём проблема sendmail на debian? Есть какие-нибудь объективные доводы против такой связки, с которыми можно придти к админу? И чем чревата такая связка? Может ли это сказаться на доставке писем или на том, что sendmail возвращает exitcode 0 при том, что у него случился какой-то факап?

Comment: да ничем, просто тот-же exim4 в разы удобнее. sendmail всё таки это скорее традиция чем надежный софт.

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо за ссылку на гитхаб PHP с кодом функции mail. В сущности, это является исчерпывающим ответом на мой вопрос. Если бы вы оформили его в виде ответа, я бы признал его лучшим и закрыл вопрос (или как тут это делается?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [место в php где это обрабатывается](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/d022c8565da4ec079cd285b245fd28e3f31a3cdb/ext/standard/mail.c#L361)
- [man 3 pclose](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pclose)